# jquery load() not working with array loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

What I am trying to do is to store a list of hundreds of files in an array and use jquery load() function to load their content one after one by a loop.

I have very little knowledge of jquery and javascript, and this is what I managed to write, but it is not working.

```
var files=['index1c.html','index23c.html'];

for(var index = 0; index < files.length; index++){
    var file = files[index];

$('#result').load('file .desc');
}
```

I think that I have some problem in variable file given in `load()` , is it the right way?
It is working fine if I directly write a single file name in place of `file` like below:

```
$('#result').load('index1c.html .desc');
```

Comment: `.load()` will overwrite the contents of `#result` every time a new file loads. Is this what you intend to happen?

Comment: @Blender: no i want content to be appended. Ya this is what load() do, I did not payed attention to this. Any solution?

Comment: "hundreds of files". Poor little server, poor little client, poor little internet.

Comment: @Engineer: If a selector is passed after the URL, jQuery uses those elements instead of the whole page.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I am doing it all on my local machine

Comment: Abhi, that's cool. All is forgiven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#result').load('file .desc');
```

To:

```
$('#result').load(file + ' .desc');
```

Note that load method removes the element's content before appending new content. You can create unique IDs like `result1`, `result2` ... and code:

```
for(var index = 0; index < files.length; index++){
    var file = files[index];
    $('#result' + (index + 1) ).load(file + ' .desc');
}
```

Or you can use classes and `eq` method:

```
var $results = $('.results')
for(var index = 0; index < files.length; index++){
    var file = files[index];
    $results.eq(index).load(file + ' .desc');
}
```

Or if you want to append the `data` you can use `$.get` utility function instead of `load` method.

Comment: any way by which I can prevent it to get overwrite and instead get it appended ?

Comment: @Abhi You can use `$.get` utility function.

Comment: A possible issue Abhi - do you need to guarantee that the files' contents are listed in the same order they were requested? With a straightforward loop-load, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @undefined: I tried using `$.get` but it looks like I need to use some server side tech to get data in proper format. I tried this code `$.get('index1c.html',function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});` but it is giving `Data Loaded: [object XMLDocument]` and when I parsed xml, it is showing `null`

Comment: @Abhi Actually both load and $.get need server to work, if you have your server running create a jQuery object from the `data` returned by server find the element and then append it, `$(data).find('.desc').appendTo('#result')`

Comment: @undefined: ok,i will try that.And the first approach you suggested of creating different `div` for each `load` .How can we dynamically create `div` before calling `load` for that particular `div`. Can you please provide me some hint or little code to get started?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the literal string `'file .desc'`.

It looks like you want `file + '.desc'`.

`'a b'` is the string `a b` whereas `a + ' b'` is the string with the contents of the variable a appended to the string `' b'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});`

`{async:false}` will hold the execution of rest code. Once you get response of ajax code, rest of the code will be executed. After executing the ajax response reset to `async` to true `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});`

So final code will be

```
var files=['index1c.html','index23c.html'];

for(var index = 0; index < files.length; index++){
    var file = files[index];
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    $('#result').load('file .desc');
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true})
}
```